# Affilatewp + woocomerce -need to add affiliate name / id to admin-new-order.php

Tags: php, email, woocommerce

I am struggling with this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

We are using AffiliateWP plugin and WooCommerce. I would love to add the Affiliate Name, ID associated with the order to the admin-new-order.php email.

This is what I tried in my functions file, but no luck.

```php
{
    // Add affiliate name to admin emails
    if ( $is_admin_email ) {
        
        add_action( "woocommerce_email_after_order_table", "custom_woocommerce_email_after_order_table", 10, 1);
    
        function custom_woocommerce_email_after_order_table( $order ) {
            echo do_shortcode( '[affiliate_name]' );
        }
        
    } // endif $is_admin_email
}
```